# Clipping symmetric difference shapefiles in Google Earth Engine

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, javascript, clip, symmetric-difference

I need to clip symmetric difference two shapefiles in Google Earth Engine. How can I do this?

I tried this code, but error:

```js
var a2 = ee.FeatureCollection(table2)
var a1 = ee.FeatureCollection(table)

var split_a = a2.symmetricDifference(a1)

Map.addLayer(split_a)
```

Comment: You always need to add the actual error message, as text, in the body of the Question.  Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked the same question on stackoverflow; I answered it there:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585906/how-to-clip-symmetric-difference-shapefiles-in-google-earth-engine/66596826#66596826